# bypass an element in filter method

Tags: javascript

Here is a code (thanks to @omgitsgod) that finds the matching phrase with the lowest performance in `slides array` based on `refer array`.

```js
var slides = [
{ id: 1, performance: 20, guided_phrases: ["I was sent", "I don't know", "to earth"] },
{ id: 2, performance: 30, guided_phrases: ["to earth"] },
{ id: 3, performance: 40, guided_phrases: ["to protect you"] },
{ id: 4, performance: 10, guided_phrases: ["I was sent"] },
{ id: 5, performance: 5, guided_phrases: ["I was sent"] }

];

let refer = ["I was sent", "to earth", "to protect you"]; // we want to check which slide id contain each refer array strings

let bypass_slide = 4; // I want to bypass this silde id 
slides.splice(bypass_slide - 1, 1); // so I just remove the bypass_slide from slides array

let id = [];

/* we just go through each string in refer array and make calculations to find the slides with the lowest performance which includes each of refer array elements*/
  for(let i = 0; i < refer.length; i++){
  
  id.push(slides.filter(x => x.performance === Math.min(...slides.filter(slide => slide.guided_phrases.includes(refer[i])).map(x => x.performance)))[0].id) 
    
    console.log(id)
}
```

This code works fine but I think a big modification is needed here:

As you can see I want to ignore and bypass slide id 4, so I just removed the slide id of `bypass_slide`, and did my calculation on the new `slides array` which I'm sure is not the best way possible.

I'm wondering if there is a solution to bypass slide id 4 by making some modification in this filter method:

```
slides.filter(x => x.performance === Math.min(...slides.filter(slide => slide.guided_phrases.includes(refer[i])).map(x => x.performance)))[0].id
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: If by "Bypass slide id 4" you mean *ignore it*, then filter it out with your initial filter. In addition to `x.performance === ...`, do `x.id !== 4`. Something like `slides.filter(x => x.id !== 4 && x.performance === ...`

Comment: let me try this...

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`

Comment: That's the result... Why?

Comment: note that in your array ```id``` (add at least an ```s``` to say it is an array), you may have elems which are of type Number but also some Array of Number. The latter can occur if the elem you push is an array: that is: two slides match the referer and have the same performance (which is also the min)

Comment: @SaraRee You would have to add it to both filters. That said, this function seems a bit rough to interpret. I might consider rewriting it in a different way, personally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) with the lowest performance and phrases as key and map then the `id` as result.

```js
var slides = [{ id: 1, performance: 20, guided_phrases: ["I was sent", "I don't know", "to earth"] }, { id: 2, performance: 30, guided_phrases: ["to earth"] }, { id: 3, performance: 40, guided_phrases: ["to protect you"] }, { id: 4, performance: 10, guided_phrases: ["I was sent"] }, { id: 5, performance: 5, guided_phrases: ["I was sent"] }],
    bypass = [4],
    map = slides.reduce((m, o) => {
        if (bypass.includes(o.id)) return m;
        o.guided_phrases.forEach(p => {
            if (!m.has(p) || m.get(p).performance > o.performance) m.set(p, o);
        });
        return m;
    }, new Map),
    refer = ["I was sent", "to earth", "to protect you", "or not"],
    result = refer.map(k => map.has(k) ? map.get(k).id : 0);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ... plus one ... but this error occurs each time that we have not an id found: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`

Comment: Here is the codepen : https://codepen.io/pixy-dixy/pen/LYYVqaX?editors=0010

Comment: what would you like to take instead?

Comment: What if we want to add a 0 when we have not found an id match

Comment: it takes time to figure out what you've done here for me... thanks for the great job...